# PHP: File getting renamed during upload if there is a space

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using the following code to upload a file in PHP for my website. I'll post the code first and then ask my question.

upload.php:

```
<html>
<form action="upload_process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Select picture to upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

upload_process.php

```
<?php
function error ($error, $location, $seconds = 1)
{
    header ("Refresh: $seconds; URL = \"$location\"");
    echo $error;
    exit;
}
$max_file_size = 1000000;
$current_directory = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) , '' , $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$uploaded_directory = $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $current_directory . 'files/';
$upload_form = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_directory . 'upload.php';
$upload_success = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_directory . 'view_posters.php';
$fieldname = 'image';
$errors = array (1 => "Max file size exceeded", 2 => "Max file size exceeded", 3 => "Upload incomplete", 4 => "No file attached");
isset ($_POST['submit']) or error ("Redirecting to upload form", $upload_form);
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0) or error ($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $upload_form);
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) or error ("Not an HTTP upload", $upload_form);
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) or error ("Please upload only images", $upload_form);
if (file_exists($upload_filename = $uploaded_directory . $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
{
    error ("File exists", $upload_form);
}
$uploadedfile = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
$newwidth = 500;
$newheight = 500;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor ($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled ($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg ($tmp, "files/" . $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'], 100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
header ("Location: " . $upload_success);
?>
```

Now, for my question, if the file name doesn't have a space, it gets resized and uploaded correctly. But, if there is a space, weird things happen. For example, if the name of the file is "this image.jpg" after upload, it gets resized and saved onto the server as "this.jpg image.jpg". Can you please tell me why this is happening.

And, $upload_success is a landing page which just says "Upload successful".

Comment: I have tried your code locally and it is working fine!

Comment: Have you tried with an image which has spaces? The file gets uploaded but have a look at the file name after it is uploaded

Comment: Yep I added a space to a filename and it still worked for me sorry fella

Comment: if file name is "this image.jpg" doesn't it become "this.jpg image.jpg" for you?

Comment: nope it becomes this image.jpg

Comment: Then why for me it is becoming "this.jpg image.jpg"? I'm so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well presumably you wouldn't want the files saving with spaces anyway. So you should be checking and correcting this as part of the upload validation.

```
imagejpeg($tmp, "files/".str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']), 100)
```

That will replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: Well now it becomes this.jpg_image.jpg and it is still a problem :(

Comment: Hmm. What's the value of `$_FILES['$fieldname]['name']`?

Comment: it is showing this.jpg image.jpg
So the problem lies here. Why is it getting converted like this?

Comment: There is nothing inherent that could cause this - it's just a form field, after all. It is surely being affected by some code - either before the submit or after. What is the value of the field on form submit?

Comment: Do you mean this? <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />

Comment: the form code is there above at the beginning of the question

Comment: No, I mean what is the *value* of the field when the form submits. I don't mean the HTML of the field.

Comment: It is the path of the file which the user selects.
Example: "C:\hello.jpg" something like that

Comment: Don't know, then. You may just have to string-handle/REGEX your way out of this one.

Comment: What is the problem? Why is it getting renamed?